# How to distinguish PSD layer types using psd.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, psd

I use psd.js to parse a PSD file on the server side. I only want plain pixel/shape layers and text layers. So I'd like to check if a Photoshop layer

1. is an adjustment layer
2. has layer mask applied
3. has vector mask applied
4. has layer styles applied
5. is a clipping mask

I've already figured out situations 4 and 5.

4. `layer.get('objectEffects')` returns an object if a layer has layer styles.
5. `layer.clippingMask()` returns an object if a layer is a clipping mask.

For situations 1-3, I have no idea how to check. Or is it possible to check using PSD.js?

BTW, PSD.js does have a `psd.tree().childrenAtPath('a_layer_path')[0].get('vectorMask')` method on layer nodes. However, the vector mask it refers to is different from the vector mask in Photoshop.